# Mongoose Populate returns [ [Object] ]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'am trying to populate boards in Product but boards property returns [ [Object] ] instead of proper data.

Server Action code block......................................................................

---

```
const product: IProduct = await Product.findById(productId)
  .populate('boards')
  .exec();

return { success: true, data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product)) };
```

Product Model

---

```
   const productSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: String,
    imageURL: String,
    imageKey: String,
    boards: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Board',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Board Model

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const boardSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: String,
    cards: [
      {
        title: String,
      },
      {
        timestamps: true,
      },
    ],
    productRelate: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Product',
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Board = mongoose?.models?.Board || mongoose.model('Board', boardSchema);

export default Board;
```

Comment: It looks like a problem with logging the data and not that the data is broken